# Automating Azure Sentinel deployment with Powershell error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sentinel

https://github.com/javiersoriano/sentinel-all-in-one/blob/master/README.md
This is basically what I am trying to do. I am trying to automate the process of deploying a SIEM, Azure Sentinel to our customers' environment to save time, but I get these errors and would not process. I got the JSON file and the ps1 file in the same folder.
[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVy8W.png)

I get these messages in the picture above. Then it proceeds to the next step which wants me to log in with my Azure account. I don't think I logged in but it proceeds without asking when I click enter.
Then I get these errors below:

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zst40.png)

Comment: Do you have the Powershell module or the CLI installed? [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-5.9.0) vs [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: I do not think so. Does that make a difference? I will try it right now.

Comment: Yes they both use 2 different command styles you need the module installed for the script you are running.

Comment: Its already on it

Comment: "The following commands are already available on this system: 'Login-AzAccount, Logout-AzAccount, Resolve-Error, Send-Feedback'.

Comment: It looks like the module isn't installed properly I would try uninstalling it and reinstalling it. Also double check that the CLI isn't installed (Do Az login) as this can cause issues.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the line to uninstall the module? I cant seem to find it. Also I do not think I have the CLI installed.

Comment: Uninstall-Module -Name Az -Force

Comment: Got an error saying: "PackageManagement\Uninstall-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module names 'Az'."

Comment: Ah then it is likely just the Az.account module was installed. In that case do `Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force` 
If this doesn't work then I am out of ideas sorry.

Comment: man, that didn't work :((